# Rails - Devise gem - Add one more check during login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise gem. I would like to add one more condition check while the user clicks in login button. So far I haven't customized create method in the sessions controller.

I would like to add a condition like if user.valid? There is one field called **valid** in the database.
What is the best way to do this with devise?

Any guidance or help would be appreciated

Comment: **Do not add a boolean field named `valid` to your table**. You're clobbering the `valid?` method from ActiveModel::Validations and breaking all the validations in your model (including the ones added by Devise). Use another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Authenticatable), the main idea is to override `active_for_authentication?`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && special_condition_is_valid?
  end
end
```